# Alberti or Caesar cipher in SQL on VARCHAR field to mask number

Tags: sql, encryption, substring, amazon-redshift, data-masking

I've used an Alberti cipher in SAS to mask numbers which works great on varying lengths. However, I'm having trouble doing the same task in Redshift SQL.

If I have a number all the same length, I could simply use a combination of substrings and to pick apart and Frankenstein a masked number. If my `COL1` is `123456789`, it would be something like:

```
substring(col1,9,1)||substring(col1,2,2)||substring(acct_num_full,3,1)||...
```

However, the column I'm trying to mask could be anywhere from 5-40 characters and so the example above would not work. I've tried `lpad` and `rpad` to standardize the lengths but it doesn't work for the shorter numbers.

Does anyone have any ideas or have done Alberti or Caesar ciphering in SQL on a varying character column? I would need an algorithm that could be reversed as well so I could decrypt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The translate() function can perform character substitutions - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_TRANSLATE.html

Just provide the caesar cypher as the chars_to_replace and chars_to_substitute strings.

===========================================

For example performing the caesar cypher example from wikipedia - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher

```
select 'THE QUICK BROWN FOX JUMPS OVER THE LAZY DOG'::text as pt
  into foo;

select pt,
 translate(pt,
           'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ',
           'XYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVW') as ct;
```

Comment: I understand this function but I'm not quite following -- can you provide a quick example with syntax?

Comment: Posted but based on your self-answer I'm thinking you are not looking for a caesar cypher.  Can you post reference on the cypher algorithm you desire if different?

Comment: Your example actually works out perfect so I'll accept this as an answer and add my edit. Easily reversible too. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to create a work-around using SAS which allows me to copy and paste the output into my SQL statement using the technique I described above with a bunch of `substring` statements:

```
/* create scaffold of column lengths */
data temp1; 
    do j=5 to 40;
        output;
    end;
run;

/* create SQL case text and randomize order of substring syntax */
data temp2; set temp1;
    do i=1 to j;
        str="substring(col1,"||strip(put(i,best.))||",1)";
        u = rand("Uniform");
        output;
    end;
run;

/* sort of column length of randomized order var */
proc sort data = temp2;
    by j u;
run;

/* put into wide format */
proc transpose data = temp2 out=wide;
    by j;
    var str;
run;

/* concatenate all SQL substring statements */
data wide1; set wide;
    format str $2000.;
    str="when length(col1)="||strip(put(j,best.))||" then "||catx("||", of col:);
    keep str;
run;

/* output as a text file and copy and paste into your SQL select staement between case ... end */
```